# Each loop setting a value to nil

Tags: ruby

I'm working with a one to many relationship in which a Workout has many Workout_drills and the Workout_drills table also belongs to a Drills table that acts a reference table. 
At the creation of a Workout, 5 Workout_drills are created which contain a randomly created Drill_id (pulling from the table of drills) and the same Workout ID for all Workout_drill records.

Here is the Workouts Controller:

```
  def show
    @workout = current_user.workouts.find(params[:id])
    @workout_drills = @workout.workout_drills
  end
```

Here is the view:

```
<% @workout_drills.each do |w| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to w.drill.name, drill_path(w) %></td>
      <td><%= w.drill.description %></td>
      <td><%= w.drill.pointers %></td>
      <% if w.drill.video.present? %>
      <td><%= link_to "Video", w.drill, class: 'btn-xs btn-success' %></td>
      <% else %>
      <td>Not Yet</td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  <%= link_to 'Begin Workout', workout_drill_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
</div>
```

For some reason, the workout_drills populate correctly when called but when I try and call the w in my terminal, the drill_id becomes nil.

I feel like this is a simple problem but I am at a loss for how to find what is happening. Any advice would be extremely helpful.

Comment: and how do u call it in the terminal

Comment: and by `w` you mean workout right ?

Comment: Yes. w stands for each workout_drill.